# How to add an event listener to an element after some specific condition?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have a tic-tac-toe game board element which appears in the UI with a 5 second animation.(opacity 0 -> 100 fade in style) And i want it to make clickable after the animation ends not right after the page loaded. How can i do that with vanilla javascript event listeners?

```
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');

cells.forEach(cell => cell.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (board[e.target.getAttribute("data-render")] === '') {
    origBoard[e.target.getAttribute("data-render")] = huPlayer;
    render();
    setTimeout(aiMove, 700);
}
}));
```

This works well but i need to activate the event listener right after the animation or "aiMove" function above executes. I don't want users can click the cells before animation ends. Animation is CSS only with @keyframes.

```
@keyframes fade-in {
    0%   { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
  }
```

Comment: `activate it` what is `it` What does the animation? Is it CSS only?

Comment: It's css only. @keyframes  animation. It = Event Listener

Answer (score 4):

You can do it many ways. Here are some examples.

**Using a flag and a setTimeout**

This means your script has to know the duration.

```js
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');
let animationComplete = false;

setTimeout(() => animationComplete = true, 5000);

cells.forEach(cell => cell.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (animationComplete) {
    console.log("You can click because the animation is over");
  }
}));
```

```html
<div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><style>.cell{padding: 20px; background: red; display: inline-block; animation: fadeIn 5s;}@keyframes fadeIn{from{opacity: 0}to{opacity: 1}}</style>
```

**Using a setTimeout and waiting before setting the event listener**

This means your script has to know the duration.

```js
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');

setTimeout(() => {
  cells.forEach(cell => cell.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log("You can click because the animation is over");
  }));
}, 5000);
```

```html
<div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><style>.cell{padding: 20px; background: red; display: inline-block; animation: fadeIn 5s;}@keyframes fadeIn{from{opacity: 0}to{opacity: 1}}</style>
```

**Using a flag and the `animationend` event**

No need to know the duration! Change it in the CSS, and JS will follow.

```js
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');
let animationComplete = false;

cells[0].addEventListener(whichAnimationEvent(), () => animationComplete = true);

cells.forEach(cell => cell.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (animationComplete) {
    console.log("You can click because the animation is over");
  }
}));

// The name of the event depends on the browser
function whichAnimationEvent(){
  var t, el = document.createElement("fakeelement");

  var animations = {
    "animation"      : "animationend",
    "OAnimation"     : "oAnimationEnd",
    "MozAnimation"   : "animationend",
    "WebkitAnimation": "webkitAnimationEnd"
  }

  for (t in animations){
    if (el.style[t] !== undefined){
      return animations[t];
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><style>.cell{padding: 20px; background: red; display: inline-block; animation: fadeIn 5s;}@keyframes fadeIn{from{opacity: 0}to{opacity: 1}}</style>
```

**Using the `animationend` event and waiting before setting the event listener**

No need to know the duration either.

```js
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');

cells[0].addEventListener(whichAnimationEvent(), () => {
  cells.forEach(cell => cell.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log("You can click because the animation is over");
  }));
});

// The name of the event depends on the browser
function whichAnimationEvent(){
  var t, el = document.createElement("fakeelement");

  var animations = {
    "animation"      : "animationend",
    "OAnimation"     : "oAnimationEnd",
    "MozAnimation"   : "animationend",
    "WebkitAnimation": "webkitAnimationEnd"
  }

  for (t in animations){
    if (el.style[t] !== undefined){
      return animations[t];
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><style>.cell{padding: 20px; background: red; display: inline-block; animation: fadeIn 5s;}@keyframes fadeIn{from{opacity: 0}to{opacity: 1}}</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to prevent mouse clicks from firing on the animated element would be via the [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) CSS property.

Applying `pointer-events:none;` to an element prevents click events from taking affect. In your case, you could add this to the CSS class that specifies animation on your game board, which would in turn prevent click events during the initial game board animation.

Here's a snippet to illustrate the idea:

```js
const gameBoard = document.querySelector(".gameBoard");

gameBoard.addEventListener("click", () => {
  alert("I respond to click events");
});

gameBoard.classList.add("animate");
console.log("1. The game board does not respond to click interaction");

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("2. The game board will now respond to click interaction");
   gameBoard.classList.remove("animate");
}, 5000);
```

```css
@keyframes fade-in {
    0%   { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
  }
 
.cell {
  background:red;
}
 
.gameBoard {
  display:grid;
  grid-gap:2px;
  grid-template-rows:repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns:repeat(2, 1fr);
  
  background:yellow;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

.gameBoard.animate {
  /* Prevent click events from firing on the gameboard
  while animation modifier class is applied */
  pointer-events:none;
  animation: fade-in 5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="gameBoard">
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, first i tried "cursor: not-allowed" property for a similar solution but then saw it doesn't work like that. It changed cursor appearance but it was still clickable. I didn't know about "pointer-events" until now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that returns this loop wrapped in setTimout.

```
function awaitAnimation() {
  return setTimout(() => (cells.forEach(cell => cell.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (board[e.target.getAttribute("data-render")] === '') {
      origBoard[e.target.getAttribute("data-render")] = huPlayer;
      render()
      setTimeout(aiMove, 700)
    }
  }))), 5000);
}
```